# Where was this picture taken (screensaver on LG Oled TV)?

Tags: identify-this, photography, winter

Can someone please tell me where this picture was taken?[image]

Answer (score 9):

Looks like Berlin to me.  That'd be the Berliner Dom.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Cathedral

Comment: It sure it. The picture is taken from James-Simon-Park at the opposite bank of the Spree river.